# A pack of playing cards, difficulty in methods and the Pack and PlayingCard Classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, methods

I have to develop a class called `Pack` and it needs to be able to generate a pack of 52 playing cards sorted by `Suit` and `Rank`. It also needs to be able to shuffle that pack of cards with another method. Finally, it has to return the `String` repesentation of that pack of cards.

This is the catch though, I have to somehow use another class I have done, `PlayingCard`, with this `Pack` class. And this is when I run into dead ends, I can't figure out a way of shuffling the cards in the arrays I use, and I can't use `PlayingCard` due to incompatability issues.

This is the current Pack Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Pack {
    int[] cards = new int[52];

    public Pack() {
        // Setting up array
        String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
        String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};

        // Intialising array
        {    
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                cards[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt(50)+1;
            cards[i] = rand;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[suit[]= " + suit[] + "rank[]= " + rank[] + "]";
    }
}
```

This is the another Pack Class based of advice, note the lack of toString():

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Pack {
    PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[52];

    public Pack() {
        // Setting up array
        String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
        String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};

        // Initialising array
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cards[i] = i;
        }   
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt(50) + 1;
            cards[i] = rand;   // Error 3
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
```

This is the template I have been using for all the good it has done:

```
Using the class PlayingCard develop another class called Pack. 
An outline for this class is provided below:
public class Pack
{
PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[];
/**
* Constructs a pack of 52 cards.
* Sorted by suit Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades.
* Sorted ascending.
*/
public Pack()
{
}
/**
* Shuffles cards in pack.
*/
public void shuffle()
{
}
/**
* @return string representation of 52 card pack.
*/
public String toString()
{
}
}
```

And finally, here is the PlayingCard class that Pack must somehow use.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class PlayingCard {
    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    public PlayingCard(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {   
        System.out.println(rank);
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        System.out.println(suit);
        return suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[rank= " + rank + "suit= " + suit + "]";
    }

    public void format() {
        System.out.format(rank + " OF " + suit);
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
        if (otherObject == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(otherObject instanceof PlayingCard)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this == otherObject) {
            return true;
        }

        PlayingCard other = (PlayingCard) otherObject;
        return suit.equals(other.suit) && rank == other.rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(suit, rank);
    }
}
```

So, how can I use the PlayingCard class with Pack, and how can I get the shuffle class in Pack to function with my arrays etc as all it is going to achieve at the moment is putting in random numbers into the cards array.

If more infomation is needed, tell me, and I will add it.

EDIT 1:

In response to the first answer, here is the enum of suit just for showing a potential problem, and the current version of Pack that I did before the answer. How does it hold out?

Enum:

```
public enum Suit 
{
    SPADES(-2), CLUBS(-1), HEARTS(0), DIAMONDS(1);

    private int value;

    private Suit(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Updated Pack:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Pack
{
    int[] cards = new int[52];

    public void Deck()
    {
        // Setting up array
        String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
        String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", 
            "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};

        // Intialising array
        {    
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
            {
                cards[i] = i;
            }
        }
   }

   public void shuffle()
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt(50)+1;
            int temp = cards[i];
            cards[i] = cards[rand];
            cards[rand] = temp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the edit is really just an write up of shuffle().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice `Rank` and `Suit` in the `PlayingCard` class. It's hint to define 2 enum classes (show only `Suit` class) :

```
public enum Suit {
   SPADE("Spade"),
   HEART("Heart"),
   DIAMOND("Diamond"),
   CLUB("Club");

   private String name;
   private Suit(String name) { this.name = name; } 

   public String toString() {return name;}
}
```

You can declare these 2 enums as `public static enum {...}` into the `Pack` class. The reason to use enums in this case is we know in advance *all* the cards and this is safer to handle strongly type objects than just `Integers` or `String` for ranks and suits.

You can then initialise the `Pack` of cards with a double loop on `Suit` and `Rank` values, e.g.

```
public Pack() {
   int i = 0;
   for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
      for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
         cards[i] = new PlayingCard(r, s);
         i++;
      }
   }
}
```

For shuffling the pack, just use `Collections.shuffle()`, e.g.

```
public void shuffle() {
    List<Card> newDeck = Arrays.asList(cards);
    Collections.shuffle(newDeck);
}
```

The `List<Card>` is backed by the array ; the shuffling is then propagated to the array of cards.

Comment: I have found only one problem with this, its that I have made a enum for both Suit and Rank, but they are both radically different from the enum you have written here, particularly due to the fact they use int(egers). See it in the edit to my question.

Comment: It's really a matter of choice for your enum between having an `Integer` value or a `String` or other attribute if it makes sens (not in this use case). I actually used `String` because you put some names in the `Pack` class. This should not cause any problems.